# Override template tag in wagtail cms?

Tags: python, django, templates, wagtail

I am using `ModelAdmin` to register a custom model with the Wagtail admin. I would like to customise the `IndexView`. The only thing I want to do is add a button to each row. I can see that the rows are added by the template tag - `results_list`, which leads me to the `results_list.html` in `modeladmin/includes`.

As this is registered with the `@register.inclusion_tag` decorator, is it possible to override the template in my own app? The normal django methods of overriding templates dont seem to be working for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the buttons for the index page by setting a custom `button_helper_class` on your ModelAdmin class: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#modeladmin-button-helper-class

(Incidentally, the tag and template are named `result_list`, not `results_list` - perhaps that's why you weren't able to override it?)

Comment: thanks; I can add a button, but how can I register the custom URL''action' to go with it? (i.e. for  `self.url_helper.get_action_url('myAction', quote(pk))`)

Comment: There seems to be more to it than just adding a new 'view' function to my `ModelAdmin`?

Comment: Ok...sorry for all the comments. I figured this out - it involves quite a lot of overriding various functions in ButtonHelper and ModelAdmin, I wonder if it can be made simpler...